# Android AppBarLayout with tabs and ViewPager

Tags: android, android-viewpager, ripple

I have a really strange issue with my app. I have `AppBarLayout` with tabs and `ViewPager`. I've configured everything for the `ViewPager`, the pages are switching on clicking the tabs but the ripple effect on the tabs (tab buttons) is interrupted on click. The problem dissapears when i move the `TabLayout` out of `AppBarLayout`, also when I add `layout:paddingTop` to `AppBarLayout` the ripple shows sometimes, but otherwise, the ripple is not showing properly except on the currently selected tab.

AppBarLayout:

```
<com.google.android.material.appbar.AppBarLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:id="@+id/app_bar_layout"
style="@style/Theme.appBarLayout">

<androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/toolbar"
    style="@style/Theme.toolbar"
    app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|snap"
    app:popupTheme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light"
    app:title="@string/app_name_text" />

<com.google.android.material.tabs.TabLayout
    android:id="@+id/home_tabs_layout"
    style="@style/Theme.tabs"
    app:tabIndicatorAnimationDuration="@android:integer/config_shortAnimTime"
    app:tabIndicatorColor="@color/primary_dark"
    app:tabIndicatorHeight="?attr/actionBarSize"
    app:tabMode="fixed"
    app:tabUnboundedRipple="false" />
```

ParentLayout:

```
<androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
style="@style/Theme.home"
tools:context=".activities.HomeActivity">

<include
    layout="@layout/actionbar_tabbed"
    app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior" />

<androidx.appcompat.widget.FitWindowsLinearLayout
    style="@style/Theme.home.container">


    <androidx.viewpager.widget.ViewPager
        android:id="@+id/home_view_pager"
        style="@style/Theme.pager"
        android:layout_below="@id/home_tabs_layout" />

</androidx.appcompat.widget.FitWindowsLinearLayout>
```

I also tried to reproduce the problem with the precreated activity given from android studio for tabs with `ViewPager`, and the behaviour was the same.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Also, look into the newer tools that Google has introduced, like Navigation Component introduced in the Jetpack set of architecture tools. See this: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Y0Cs2MQxyIs

Answer (score 0):

Look for the below xml code

```
<com.google.android.material.tabs.TabLayout
            android:id="@+id/tabLayout"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
            app:tabBackground="?attr/selectableItemBackgroundBorderless"
            app:tabGravity="fill"
            app:tabIndicatorHeight="0dp"
            app:tabMode="fixed"
            app:tabUnboundedRipple="true" />
```

Notice here the two lines

`app:tabBackground="?attr/selectableItemBackgroundBorderless" 
OR 
app:tabBackground="?attr/selectableItemBackground`"

And

```
app:tabUnboundedRipple="true"
```

Comment: I've tried this, but unfortunately it does not work.

Comment: This happens only when i use view pager with Fragments, It seems to be connected with the onTabSelected event.